# Button in a listview - android

Tags: android

I have a class that extends `ListActivity` with a `SimpleAdapter` as the list adapter. My code looks like this:

```
public class ListOfFirms extends ListActivity {

    Intent extras;
    int time;
    String km;
    ArrayList<String> firms = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    SimpleAdapter adapter;  
    static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firms);
            
        extras = getIntent();
            
        time = extras.getIntExtra("time", 0); 
        km = extras.getStringExtra("km");
                  
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this, list, R.layout.taxi_custom,
            new String[] {"name","price"},
            new int[] {R.id.taxi_name,R.id.taxi_price});
          
            initializeFirm();
            setListAdapter(adapter);
     }
}
```

My question is how I can add a button to each element in the list, the button should be floating to right. My list contains object of the class `Firm`, how can I know which object that I grab out from the list, when a user presses this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/dynamic-custoized-list-view-in-android.html) is example of custom listview which may help you

use custom adapter....
and set

```
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a CustomAdapter which extends BaseAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use OnTouchListener and OnLongClickListener instead of a button it is a little easier to implement. Also if you just want to select the item, it ies easier tu use the standard built-in Android mechanisms.

Only if you REALLY need a button on each list item you have to do it like Gaurav Agarwal suggested... - which is something you might have to do sooner or later anyway :-)