# Android listview with ArrayList

Tags: java, android, listview, listactivity

I just wanted to use `ListView` without extending `ListActivity` (because I'm extending my abstract class with actionbar). So, how to use simple ArrayList with it? I tried:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.list);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, myArrayList));
```

But my app crashed with error on the last line `(lv.setAdapter......).` What should I do, please?

EDIT:

https://gist.github.com/2481484

Comment: can you paste your error log and relevant code?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10271033/1289716

Comment: Thanks, but looks too complex for this simple task. But I'll have a look closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lv` variable is `null` because you are trying to get your `ListView` via `R.layout.list`. You should get it via `R.id.your_list_id`.

Also, you shouldn't use ListViews with regular Activities like this. You should use a ListActivity instead. You can check how to use it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: I disagree.  ListActivity is just one ListView and that's it.  Most of the time, more functionality, UI components, etc are needed.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that... but in his case it's still better to use a ListActivity right? Or should I change my answer?

Comment: I can't use ListView, because I'm extending another class. And thank you, R.id.list works great!